# Why is it a Bad Thing for one process to be able to read, or even write, to memory occupied by a different process?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I am new to Operating System

Why is it a Bad Thing for one process to be able to read, or even write, to memory occupied by a different process?

If I am not wrong , Data of a process may be overwritten if another process access it, but what is the problem if another process is allowed to read ?, Thanks .

Comment: It's not that it's good or bad, but in a system with virtual memory, each process gets its own virtual address space. Shared memory has to be setup so that multiple processes can read and write the same physical memory.  Note -each process may have a different virtual address to that same physical memory.

Comment: If another process is able to read memory from other process, there can be a massive security disaster. To elaborate, sensitive data from the process where the read memory belongs to can be retrieved and an attacker may gain access to a system.